# Missing argument in Django tutorial

Tags: python, django

I have been starting to learn Django right now and as I was doing a tutorial, I got an error. After changing the views like in the tutorial, part 4 I started to get an error that some argument is missing.

`Reverse for 'votes' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/votes/\\Z']`

I searched on google about that problem and other people had the same issue, but it was like problem with correct spelling. In my problem I had missing argument called `question` in `details.html`. I tried with the for loop and it helps but my answers didn't showing up.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Questions, Choice


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "polls/index.html"
    context_object_name = "latest_question_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        "Return latest 5 questions"
        return Questions.objects.order_by("-pub_date")[:5]


class DetailsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Questions
    template_name = "polls/details.html"


class ResponseView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Questions
    template_name = "polls/response.html"


def votes(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Questions, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST["choice"])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(
            request,
            "polls/details.html",
            {"question": question, "error_message": "You didn't select a choice"},
        )
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("polls:response", args=(question.id,)))
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


app_name = "polls"
urlpatterns = [
    path("<int:question_id>/votes/", views.votes, name="votes"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.DetailsView.as_view(), name="details"),
    path("<int:pk>/response/", views.ResponseView.as_view(), name="response"),
    path("", views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
]
```

details.html:

```
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'polls:votes' question.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1></legend>
            {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
            {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
                <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
                <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Vote">
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Like I said, I tried adding for loop to define my argument but it doesn't work perfect. I will be very grateful for help.

Thank you <3

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855143/reverse-for-vote-with-arguments-not-found-1-patterns-tried-app1? Check if helps.

Comment: Thanks, @pKiran the same problem as my. After changing context, everything works! I don't know why I wasn't able to find that question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: \['app1/(?P<question\_id>\[0-9\]+)/vote/$'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855143/reverse-for-vote-with-arguments-not-found-1-patterns-tried-app1)

Comment: @aaron Yes! Changing context for DetailsView and ResponseView helped me.

`context_object_name = "question"`

Answer (score 0):

The error message `.... with arguments '('',)' not found. ...` just tells you that the argument is empty in an urls tag like here question.id

```
{% url 'polls:votes' question.id %}
```

in your case question is empty because the default 'context-object-name' for the model is `object` in the template for Generic Class Based Views. So object.id should work.

Now with the for loop added if you want to use `latest_question_list` in details.html

```
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
```

you need to add in the View:

```
class DetailsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Questions
    template_name = "polls/details.html"
    context_object_name = "latest_question_list"
```

but I suppose that this is not the target as it is the detail view and you just wanted to solve the missing argument problem above.

Comment: That's answer for my problem. After changing context to `question` it works. Thank you!